# How can I “tighten” the curvature of an exponential function to satisfy three given points?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to map a range:

$$0 \le x \le 1$$

non-linearly to another range:

$$0.01 \le y \le 4$$

where $x = 0.5$ must map to $y = 1$.  Essentially, I have three known points:

```
x  0.00  0.50  1.00
y  0.01  1.00  4.00
```

and $y$ cannot ever be $\lt 0.01$ (I mention this explicitly because I have also toyed with quadratics in an attempt to solve this problem).

My distant high-school maths memories tell me that I need an **exponential** function to achieve this.  To that end, I followed the instructions in $\infty+1$'s YouTube video, [Write an Exponential Equation Given 3 Points](https://youtu.be/fsYZ5OLrrwg), and worked from $y = ar^x + c$ to arrive at this very-close solution:

$$ y = \frac{13167}{6700}\cdot\left(\frac{100}{33}\right)^{x}-\frac{131}{67} $$

This solution satisfies $(0,0.01)$ and $(1,4)$, but not $(0.5,1)$.  I guess I need to somehow “tighten” the curve such that the $y$ values for $0 \le x \le 0.5$ are lower without affecting point $(1,4)$, but I'm at a loss as to how I might do this.  I guess I have chosen the wrong exponential equation to start from.

Should I be starting from another exponential equation, and should I be able to solve this with my reasonably basic maths skills of algebra and simultaneous equations (and not enough understanding to know where to start with terms like *regression*, *monotone*, and *differentiable* as found in answers to similar questions)?

Comment: To be clear, what kind of accuracy do you expect ? You want to do the same fiting error for the three points ?

Comment: @nicomezi, I'm hoping to find an exactly-defined solution if this is possible.  I understand that I might be able to generate approximations using online tools or Excel, but this function is going into software and any inaccuracies at the defined points—especially $(0, 0.01)$—could result in crashes.

Comment: Do you mean $x=.5$ maps to $y=1$ or $x=.05$ maps to $y=1$?  You say both.

Comment: I think that you made a few mistakes in the calculations.

Comment: @saulspatz, the $.05$ is a typo.  Sorry about that.  Fixed.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, this is very possible.  I know I made at least one significant error in my first attempt.  I'm also not entirely sure that my $(0.5, 1)$ point was used directly in my calculations.  It's probably a very good thing that no one's lives depend on my mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $y = ar^x + c$ and using whole numbers as you obviously did, we have three equations
$$a+c=\frac{1}{100} \tag 1$$
$$a \sqrt{r}+c=1 \tag 2$$
$$a r+c=4 \tag 3$$ Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ and $(1)$ from $(3)$; $c$ is no more here
$$a \sqrt{r}-a=\frac{99}{100}\tag 4$$
$$a r-a=\frac{399}{100} \tag 5$$
From $(5)$
$$a=\frac{399}{100 (r-1)}\tag 6$$ Plug in $(4)$ to get
$$\frac{300-99 \sqrt{r}}{100 \left(\sqrt{r}+1\right)}=0 \implies \sqrt r=\frac {300}{99}=\frac{100}{33}\implies r=\frac{10000}{1089}$$ back to $a$ and $c$
$$y=\frac{3267}{6700} \left(\frac{10000}{1089}\right)^x-\frac{32}{67}$$

**Edit**

If you have three points $(0,y_1)$, $(0.5,y_2)$, $(1,y_3)$, the generic formulae are
$$a=\frac{(y_1-y_2)^2}{y_1-2 y_2+y_3}\qquad r=\left(\frac{y_2-y_3}{y_1-y_2}\right)^2\qquad c=\frac{y_1 y_3-y_2^2}{y_1-2 y_2+y_3}$$

This can be generalized for three points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ if $x_2=\frac 12 (x_1+x_3)$ using as intermediate variable $t=\frac{x-x_1}{x_3-x_1}$ and the formual becomes
$$y= ar^{\frac{x-x_1}{x_3-x_1}}+c$$ $(a,r,c)$ being the same as just above.

Comment: (+1) Slightly quicker to divide (5) by (4) to get $\surd r+1=399/99$ directly.

Comment: @JohnBentin. You are correct and I am stupid ! Cheers :-(

Comment: Thank you so much, @ClaudeLeibovici.  I am studying your answer, because I will shortly need to repeat this for $(0, 0.2)$ instead of $(0, 0.01)$.  I am especially trying to understand “Plug in $(4)$ to get...” more clearly.

Comment: @JohnBentin, thank you too.  I am having some difficulty understanding the transformations in the line underneath $(6)$, but with your shortcut for determining $r$, it is perhaps not an issue.  In any case, with the clear instructions in this answer I have successfully recalculated for a different initial point of $(0, 0.2)$. 

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, your edit has actually addressed a problem I didn't even know I had yet—all three $y$ values will in fact be variable.  If I could give you a double upvote, I would.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to add another answer for the problem of the curvature.*

Back to the original problem with data points $(0,y)$, $(0.5,1.0)$, $(1,4)$ the parameters are given by
$$a=\frac{(y-1)^2}{y+2}\qquad r=\frac{9}{(y-1)^2}\qquad c=\frac{4 y-1}{y+2}$$For $f(x)=a r^x+c$, the curvature at $x=0.5$ is given by
$$\kappa=\frac{a (\log (r)+2)}{2 \sqrt{r} \left(1+a^2 r \log ^2(r)\right)^{3/2}}$$ which would give the awful
$$\kappa=\frac{(1-y)^3 (y+2)^2 \left(2+\log (9)-2\log \left(1-y\right)\right)}{6
   \left((y+2)^2+9 (1-y)^2 \log ^2\left(\frac{9}{(1-y)^2}\right)\right)^{3/2}}\tag 1$$ Since $y \ll 1$, we can expand as a Taylor series to get, as an *approximation*,
$$\kappa=\frac{2 (2+\log (9))}{3 \left(4+9 \log ^2(9)\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{ (2 \log (9) (9 (\log (9)-2) \log (9)-122)-40)}{3 \left(4+9 \log
   ^2(9)\right)^{5/2}}y+\cdots$$ which, numerically is
$$\kappa=0.0085608 -0.0120139 y$$ from which you can compute the value of $y$ for the desired curvature.

Using $(1)$, as a function of $y$, some values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.00 & 0.00856080 \\
 0.01 & 0.00844115 \\
 0.02 & 0.00832246 \\
 0.03 & 0.00820472 \\
 0.04 & 0.00808791 \\
 0.05 & 0.00797201 \\
 0.06 & 0.00785702 \\
 0.07 & 0.00774292 \\
 0.08 & 0.00762968 \\
 0.09 & 0.00751730 \\
 0.10 & 0.00740577 \\
 0.11 & 0.00729507 \\
 0.12 & 0.00718518 \\
 0.13 & 0.00707609 \\
 0.14 & 0.00696779 \\
 0.15 & 0.00686027 \\
 0.16 & 0.0067535 \\
 0.17 & 0.00664749 \\
 0.18 & 0.00654221 \\
 0.19 & 0.00643765 \\
 0.20 & 0.00633381
\end{array}
\right)$$